# is wcf rest weboperationcontext.current thread safe?

Tags: wcf, rest, multithreading

I'm currently returning a stream from all my WebGet/WebInvoke decorated methods from WCF. And I also get a stream as input. I do this because I want flexibility with response & input content types. This is primarily because I need flexibility when parsing the input - it cannot be easily serialized / deserialized.

However I then use the WebOperationContext.Current to set httpstatuscodes. I'm concerned this wouldn't be thread safe though (how would the thread know which context it was processing?)

So my question is - is using WebOperationContext.Current thread-safe under high load conditions?

Does anyone know how the thread and WebOperationContext.Current are linked? Is it using TLS (thread local storage)?

p.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of [WebOperationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.weboperationcontext.aspx) states:

> Any public static (Shared in Visual
>   Basic) members of this type are thread
>   safe. Any instance members are not
>   guaranteed to be thread safe.

This means that invoking [Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.weboperationcontext.current.aspx) is thread safe because it is static, but invoking any method on the returned instance will not be guaranteed to be thread safe.